# Are variables always global with NXT?

Tags: nxt, programming

New to NXT software. What I'm trying to do is get my motor to go one of 5 distances, but I'm not sure how to choose between those actions. What I thought of was setting 5 variables to 5 sensors. The idea is that if I activate 1 of 5 sensors (left button, enter button, right button, touch sensor, sound sensor), it will know which of the 5 variables are usable and simply does that.

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, global.

5 variables may be 4 more than required. I think one is enough.

```
Set intSensor = 0
Loop until intSensor > 0
    If leftButton then intSensor = 1
    If rightButton then intSensor = 2    
    If enterButton then intSensor = 3
    If bumped1 then intSensor = 4
    If soundVal > 50 then intSensor = 5
End Loop
If intSensor = 1 then moveForward(135)
. . .
```